# Is there a USB Wireless device emulator for Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, virtualbox, virtual-machine, usb-device

I would like to have a Wireless device available in a Linux VirtualBox machine, but VirtualBox doesn't offer the option to expose the builtin PC Wireless device to the VM.

It's possible to purchase a USB Wireless device and expose it to the VM, but I thought that maybe a virtual USB Wireless device exists and can be installed in the host and then have this device exposed to the VM.

Comment: Couldn't the VM's "wired" interface just route thru the laptop's wireless device?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco Yes, the VM can use the internet connection provided by the Wireless device, but this is not what I want. I want to have a "physical" wireless device available for the VM, currently VirtualBox only exposes devices as cable NICs. I need to test Linux programs like `iwconfig` and for this I need a wireless device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in virtualbox, but you can pass through a wifi interface with kvm.
Consider that when you do it, the interfase must belong to it's own IOMMU group, or you must pass through all the devices in that IOMMU group

Of course that's not an emulation, that transpassing the device directly to the VM.